# Usar jQuery em um arquivo JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, aplicação-web

Sou iniciante e gostaria de uma ajuda, se possível...
Eu tenho arquivo **index.html**, o qual estou importando o jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Eu quero escrever os scripts dessa página em outro arquivo (no meu caso, **index.js**).
Já estou importando esse arquivo JS no meu arquivo HTML:

```
<script src="script/index.js"></script>
```

Ou seja, quero usar o jQuery nesse arquivo index.js para interagir com o index.html.
Usei o `import $ from 'jquery'`, mas não funciona.
Fiz outro teste instalando o jQuery via NPM e importando na página index.html, mas também não consigo importar na página index.js.
O erro que aparece no console do browser é:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Como, então, posso importar o jQuery em um arquivo JS para que eu posso desenvolver as interações de um arquivo HTML?

Comment: Leia isso aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Hoisting veja se ajuda.

Comment: Queira [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema para viabilizar o post.

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa fazer nenhuma declaração dentro do **index.js**, se você incluir as chamadas para os dois scripts, você pode usar normalmente o jquery no seu arquivo js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<script src="script/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode seguir os passos que estão [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515921/5331941) de uma pergunta similar à sua no Stack Overflow em inglês.

> Se você quer incluir código jQuery de outro arquivo JS, o seguinte deve servir:
>
> Eu tinha o seguinte no meu arquivo HTML:
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
> <script src="my_jquery.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Criei um arquivo my_jquery.js separado com o seguinte:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('a').click(function(event) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     $(this).hide("slow");
>   });
> });
> ```

Espero que isso te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto o jQuery, quanto qualquer outro arquivo JS deve ser importado no deu head de cada HTML que for utiliza-los.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
      <script src="script/index.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```